# How to get VS2010 Web.config Transformations working from NAnt?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, nant

In my Nant file I've got (paths shortened):

```
<echo message="#### TARGET - compile ####"/>
<echo message=""/>
<echo message="Build Directory is ${build.dir}" />

<exec program="${framework}\msbuild.exe"
      commandline="..\src\Solution.sln /m /t:Clean /p:Configuration=Release" />

<exec program="${framework}\msbuild.exe"
      commandline="..\src\Solution.sln /m /t:Rebuild  /p:Configuration=Release" />

<exec program="${framework}\msbuild.exe"
      commandline="..\src\Solution.sln /m /t:TransformWebConfig /p:Configuration=Release" />
```

Which results in:

```
Build FAILED.       "C:\..\src\Solution.sln" (TransformWebConfig target) (1) ->         C:\..\src\Solution.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "TransformWebConfig" does not exist in the project. [C:\..\src\Solution.sln]    0 Warning(s)    1 Error(s)Time Elapsed 00:00:00.05
```

The solution and associated projects are all VS2010 and the Web Application even has the correct reference in the .csproj:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

Shouldn't this just work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, it isn't a problem specific to NAnt, you just can't call `TransformWebConfig` on a solution file.

**Solutions :**

- Call it on your project file :

  ```
   <exec program="${framework}\msbuild.exe"
         commandline="..\src\WebApp\WebApp.csproj /m /t:TransformWebConfig /p:Configuration=Release" />
  ```
- Override the `AfterBuild` target in your project file to call TransformWebConfig :

  ```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="TransformWebConfig"/>
  </Target>
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get it working with the TransformWebConfig option nor the AfterBuild Target, However, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983575/copywebapplication-with-web-config-transformations) was the answer for me. In short, this is what my "build" target looks like in Nant:

```
<target name="build" description="Compiles/Builds the Solution">
<echo message="Building..." />
<property name="build.configuration" value="Release" />

<msbuild project="${path::combine(staging.project,'_solutions\mySolutionName.sln')}" verbosity="minimal" failonerror="true" verbose="false">
    <arg value="/p:Configuration=${build.configuration};OutputPath=${path::combine(staging.output,'bin')}" />
    <arg value="/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True" />
    <arg value="/p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False" />
    <arg value="/p:WebProjectOutputDir=${staging.output}\" />
    <arg value="/t:Rebuild" />
    <arg value="/nologo" />
</msbuild>
<echo message="Building finished..." />
```

All the files needed for the website to run are copied into the specified "WebProjectOutputDir" property, including the web.Config with the transformations applied. it worked like a charm :)

-Diego

Comment: Setting `UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True` is the trick - thanks!