# MSBuild output missing javascript files compiled by Typescript

Tags: msbuild, typescript

We use MSBuild on our CI server to compile our WebApp, however the build omits the JavaScript files built by TypeScript from the output of the build.

I would expect the output to contain the JavaScript and not the Typescript, however neither are in the output at the expected locations.

How can I include the JavaScript files without having to have them all in my solution?  The TypeScript team seems to think this is bad, but I would rather not have duplicates of all the files in my solution either.

Comment: Hi @Gent, I was wondering if you got it to work? Please let me know if you still have a problem with this.

Comment: @MrMathos I got it figured out, however the typescript installation was present on the build server so it ended up being a different issue than detailed in your answer.  Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: No problem, glad you found it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was due to using MSBuild instead of the "Publish" on the build server it seems.  I added an AfterBuild target to content include all of the JS files to the build output.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="**\*.js" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Although this is not ideal, it allows the js files not to show in the solution when using visual studio and the files end up in the build output.

Comment: let me ask you - when you added this it actually puts the files on the target server? I'm in a similar situation where I got my whole deal working using publish locally, but when I actually ran the same .csproj setup on the actual build server by queueing a build, it didn't work.

Comment: Yep, it works through msbuild on jenkins and via octopus deploy as well, as long as its added to the csproj itself

Comment: This is so weird, why would mine not copy the files to the target server? It doesn't put them in the _publishedwebsites folder, nor the target server itself. I basically just used what you have above. Was there anything else?

Comment: Have you verified that the js files exist in place after build?  For example if you had "Scripts/SomeLibrary.ts" you find a "Scripts/SomeLibrary.js"

Answer (score 5):

I tried many solutions from the web including the `<Content Include="**\*.js" />`, but nothing worked.  I'm using MSBuild on my local dev box and typescript is installed and targets available in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript`.

It turns out my "old" MSBuild runner for web app csproj files is obsolete.  I was doing this:

```
MSBuild.exe my.csproj /Target:ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication /property:WebProjectOutputDir=myfolder;OutDir=myfolder\bin;Configuration=Debug
```

but thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953376/1089267) I need to use `UseWPP_CopyWebApplication` instead of the legacy `_CopyWebApplication`:

```
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild "/p:WebProjectOutputDir=myfolder;OutDir=myfolder\bin;Configuration=Debug;UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True;PipelineDependsOnBuild=False" my.csproj
```

Now without any editing of the csproj file, all my TypeScript is included!

Comment: Thank you! This should be marked as the answer. The answer you've linked to investigated and found the root of the problem coming from a poor decision by Microsoft in their Publish task target file.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is probably not installed on your build server. To install it, copy your TypeScript folder from `c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\` to the same folder on your build server (where `v12` is the version of your Visual Studio).

The Visual Studio version on your build server can be different however. In my situation, the version on my development machine is `v12`, while the build server uses `v11`. I found that out by adding the following to the `[WebProjectName].csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="PrintVisualStudioInfo">
    <Message Text="VisualStudioVersion: '$(VisualStudioVersion)'" Importance="High" />
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
    <CompileDependsOn>
        PrintVisualStudioInfo;
        $(CompileDependsOn)
    </CompileDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Be sure you put it after the last `<Import />` element. Now when you look at the output of your build on the build server, you should see 'VisualStudioVersion: *xx*' somewhere.

Copy the `TypeScript` folder to the correct version folder on the build server.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding in case it helps people.
We had this issue recently and it was fixed by adding 
`/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0` to the BAT file :

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe FullBuild.proj /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /t:createRelease /p:ReleaseNumber=5.22.0
```