# What is the purpose of PipelineDependsOnBuild property in MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration

I am in charge of maintain some build scripts intended to be used with MSBuild; I have found that they have several properties, among them I found the code:

```
/p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False
```

Looking for an explanation about this, I search the web and I found that is part of the solution of issues with the building process of web projects, but is used in combination with other properties.

So far I have not found an msdn page that explain the purpose of that.

Fact: I tried to search for  `/p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=True`  and no results were found

Comment: Do you have an issue with that property - than please describe it - or are you just curious? You can try to find out the purpose by reading the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets` (or your equivalent for other VS versions). As it stands it seems to really be only related to the (publishing) of Web projects.

Comment: I do not have any issue with it, I'm just curious. I will read the Web publising targets

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, as I too found the use of this particular property curious, yet can't find any reference myself. However, in the said `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets` file, this comments are interesting:

> "These two Properties are not compatable  %24(UseWPP_CopyWebApplication) and  %24(PipelineDependsOnBuild) both are True.
> Please correct the problem by either set %24(Disable_CopyWebApplication) to true or set %24(PipelineDependsOnBuild) to false to break the circular build dependency.
> Detail: %24(UseWPP_CopyWebApplication) make the publsih pipeline (WPP) to be Part of the build and %24(PipelineDependsOnBuild) make the WPP depend on build thus cause the build circular build dependency.  " />

So that using the `PipelineDependsOnBuild=False` might be necessary in order to using `UseWPP_CopyWebApplication' option.

Comment: And see the link for that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983575/copywebapplication-with-web-config-transformations/2953376#2953376